# Storing the value of 'bitsadmin /getstate myDownloadJob into a variable in a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am having an issue,

I am running a job using bitsadmin and I want a more detailed state of the job for the people using it.

```
bitsadmin /getbytestotal myDownloadJob
bitsadmin /getbytestransferred myDownloadJob
```

I would like to store the result of this into a variable. I tried parsing it to a txt file by the warning of bitsadmin being deprecated is all over it.

Ideally I just want it stored into a variable, I'm going to echo it so a txt is not required.

Any help please :D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off

for /f %%$ in ('bitsadmin /getbytestotal myDownloadJob') do set "bytesTotal=%%$"
for /f %%$ in ('bitsadmin /getbytestransferred myDownloadJob') do set "bytestransferred=%%$"


echo bytestransferred - %bytestransferred%
echo bytesTotal - %bytesTotal%
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I haven't tested this, but do you think you could explain it for me? does this just pickup what bytestotal returns? and %%$, what does this do..? I've tried using google to resolve this. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike to parse what a command returns you need `FOR /F`  - in this case the last line of the commands is stored in two variables bytestransferred  and bytesTotal

Comment: Thanks, Just tested this and it worked.. What about %%$? google excludes this from my search

Comment: @Mike - its a token that means 'this part of the command output' (you can few of them) - http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html